# If condition not working in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am using the below if condition to do some task in my script, but it is not 
working as expected. Can someone please tell me if i am wrong.

```
if [ `whoami` != 'user1' ]|[ `whoami` != 'user2' ]; then
  echo "Must run this script as user1 or user2."
  exit
else
  do something 
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[ `whoami` != 'user1' ]|[ `whoami` != 'user2' ]
```

so you're using the `[` test command, which returns true or false and has no output, and then *piping* the empty output to *another* `[` test.

The return status of a pipeline is just the result of the *last* command. So, this is equivalent to

```
[ `whoami` != 'user2' ]
```

What you wanted was perhaps

```
[ (`whoami` != 'user1') -a (`whoami` != 'user2') ]
```

which is a single test command with a boolean **and**.

(Your code *looks* more like it should be a logical **or**, but that doesn't match the program logic).

---

Running `whoami` twice seems unnecessary - the value may already be in `$USER`, but if you don't want to trust that, you could probably refactor your code into something like

```
case $(whoami) in
user1|user2) ;; # OK - continue below esac
*) echo "Must run this script as user1 or user2."
   exit ;;
esac
# do something
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wanted boolean AND instead of OR. Otherwise this can never become false.

Comment: Yeah, I just re-read the question and realised that, I was thrown by the assumption that `|` was intended as `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two conditions using `-a` ("user is not user1 and user is not user2"):

```
if [ `whoami` != 'user1' -a `whoami` != 'user2' ]; then
```

See `man test` for more information. Note that `test` a.k.a. `[` is built into the bash shell rather than being a separate binary, so it's also buried in `man bash` somewhere.